# How to find current value of variable from logic app instance?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Inside my logic app, I am initializing a variable and this variable's value can change over the course of logic app execution. While logic app is still in running mode (waiting for external event to happen) I want a way to find the current value of the variable in logic app.

I can always store value of this variable in data store like SQL server or blob storage and read it from there but I don't want to use external storage. Given that logic apps are kind of stateful in a way, I am wondering if there is a way to get variable value.

Answer (score 1):

So, there isn't a way to peek at the state of a Logic App while it's running.  Some data might be available in the Run History, but that's not necessarily real-time and there no easy way to correlate it with any external info.

That means an external mechanism is you're only practical solution, but *there's nothing wrong with that*.

My suggestion would be an **Azure Function + Redis Cache**.  The Logic App can update its state periodically by some key value, [LogicAppName]+[OrderID] for example, then another client can query on that same pattern.

Eventually, you may want to elevate this to Application Insights if you fine the need to track the entire app or business processes.

Answer (score 0):

I use simple action like [Http POST action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http) with fake url and "post" my variable in the post data.
if you need it to run on the actual environment (not only when debugging) you can set the [Configure run after](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling#customize-run-after-behavior) to continue even when the HTTP step failed.