# azure Logic app poll status with javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-logic-apps

I'am currently implementing a logic app which is triggerd by an javascript over http request.
Because the Logic App Reposnse will timeout after 120 seconds, the idea is to poll the status of the logic app with a second javascript request.

Did someone implemented a feature like this or is there another way to bypass the 120 seconds timeout?

Best regards

Comment: You could find that Request timeout 120s is the [limitation of Azure logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#timeout)

Comment: Yes i know that is the limitation. But as mentioned in my question I want to write a javascript function that checks every 2 seconds the status of the running logi app... But I don't know how and couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question just came up and my Answer there is that an external mechanism is the only practical way to achieve this...but there is nothing wrong with that.

An Azure Function + Redis cache is a good start.

Similar Answer is here: [How to find current value of variable from logic app instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573610/how-to-find-current-value-of-variable-from-logic-app-instance/48584384#48584384)